# All Tags Are Not Displayed in Segments (MailChimp)

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

In my MailChimp Segment,  not displaying all my tags and i want to get id's of that tags.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public List GetAllListSegments()

```
        =>_mailChimpManager.ListSegments.GetAllAsync(ListId).Result.ToList();
```

Call ListSegment method , get iterator and  save all tags in a file one by one.